# Should I be using try/catch?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array, try-catch

I am doing some practice problems and the current problem I am working on involves me constantly checking surrounding values in a 2D array.

I am wondering what is the best way to go about handling `out of bounds exceptions` for a problem like this. Should I be using `try-catch` blocks for each index I am checking? The catch part would not be utilized in this case since I wouldn't want to print anything or end the program if an error occurs. This is why I think there may be a better way to handle this.

This is some simplified code for the "index checking"

```java
private static void findRoute(String[][] area, int currentRow, int currentCol) {
    int row = currentRow;
    int col = currentCol;

    while (!area[row][col].equals("D")) {
        try {
            checkRight(area, row, col);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException io) {
            //Move on
        }

        try {
            checkLeft(area, row, col);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException io) {
            //Move on
        }
    }
}
```

So, for example, if the first `try-catch block` results in an error, I would want it to move onto the next `try-catch` to check the next value.

However, if there is no error, I want to check the value at the index I was using the `try-catch` block on. But if I put a statement after the try-catch to get the value of `checkRight()`, and the error in the `try-catch` was thrown, then it would just give me an error and the program would crash.

Should I be handling this in a different way? Is there an easier way to handle this with `if-statements` or something?

Comment: *what the best way to go about handling out of bounds exceptions*: the best way is to **avoid** those exceptions, by not accessing out of bounds indices in the first place. So no, you shouldn't be using try/catch here.

Comment: To add to what JB has said - what you really want to do is check the indexes against the dimensions of the array before you attempt access that combination..

Comment: What does "Move On" means? if you want to try `checkLeft` if `CheckRight` throws this exception then do the second try-catch in the first catch. If you don't want the second try-catch to happend if the first try passed, use `continue;` to restart the loop

Comment: Make a boundary of zeros around your data so you don’t have to check.

Answer (score 0):

In general, an exception is something which does not adhere to a rule. You expect some things and they should mostly fulfill the expectations you have, but in some exceptional cases your expectations are not met. If you ponder about this, you will realize that since softwares can have different levels, what is an exception on a lower level is not necessarily an exception in higher level and vice-versa.

The main mistake you make in organizing your code is that your concern of index bounds is handled on the level of `findRoute` and not on its proper level, that is, in your `checkLeft` and `checkRight` methods. On the level of `findRoute`, you kind of expect to have some edge cases (literally), yet, on the level of `checkLeft` and `checkRight` you need to handle this. As a result, you should move all your concern about bounds into `checkLeft` and `checkRight`. If you see value in handling out of bounds as an exception for logging or any other purpose, then you can have a try-catch on the level of these methods, but you should ensure that they handle it. For example you can modify these methods to be `boolean` and return `true` at the end of the `try` and `false` at the end of the `catch`, `like`

```
try {
    //Do some stuff
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Do some stuff
    return false;
}
```

and then you can do something like this:

checkRight(area, row, col) || checkLeft(area, row, col);

Don't worry: if `checkRight` is `true`, `checkLeft` will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` statement instead of `try-catch` construct because it is *less expensive*:

```java
private static void findRoute(String[][] area, int row, int col) {
    // index checking
    if (row < area.length && col < area[row].length) {
        // do some stuff
    } else {
        // do another stuff
    }
}
```